# X-Editable Save With A Custom Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, x-editable

Here is a link to my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v58breo8/1/

I was wondering if id was possible to save my updated input to the page by clicking the save button. If you try to edit and then click save then the text will not have been changed.

I would also like the user to only be able to save their text when they hit the save button, right now if you hit enter after editing then it will act normally and the text will change.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.showbuttons = false;
$.fn.editable.defaults.type = 'text';

$('#edit-btn').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  $('#username').editable('toggle');
    $('#edit-btn').addClass('hidden');
  $('#save-btn').removeClass('hidden');
});

$('#save-btn').click(function(){
            $('#username').editable({
        success: function (response, newValue) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { user: newValue},
                url: '/post'
            });
        },
        name: 'username',
        pk: 1,
        placement: 'top',
        type: 'text',
        toggle: 'manual'
    });

    $('#edit-btn').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#save-btn').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: why you dont set the text in the success function?

Comment: @Azd325 shouldn't x-editable handle that for me? Or is there something that I have to add to the success function in order to do that?